# SQL connection error showing INVALID OBJECT NAME

Tags: sql, connection

I have done follwing coding but it shows error

### Invalid object name 'sanket'

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim str As String

```
Private Sub ConnectToSQL()
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SA_N_KET-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=repeat;Integrated Security=true;"
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
    Finally
        'DoNothing.
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CryrptDataSet.sanket' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.SanketTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CryrptDataSet.sanket)
    ConnectToSQL()
End Sub
Public Sub exe()
    str = "insert into sanket(n)values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(Str, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "sanket")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    exe()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: can you please post the error ?

Comment: it shows error like this : invalid object name sanket

Comment: yes, sanket is table.. and i am using MSSQLSERVER 2005